# Difficulty parsing combinatorics exercise

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning, integer-partitions

I am working through the wonderful book *Proofs and Confirmations* by David Bressoud. In the section 2.2, I came across the following exercise, which has me scratching my head.

> (2.2.8) ~ Let $a(m,n)$ be the number of **representations** of $m$ as the sum of integers in two partitions **into** distinct parts for which the first partition must have exactly $n$ more **elements** than the second, and the second is allowed to have $0$s. If $n$ is negative, then the second parition has exactly $-n$ more elements than the first. […] Find a bijection between the partitions counted by $a(m,n)$ and those counted by $a(m-n,-n)$.

[emphasis added]

My best guess at what this is saying is that we are looking at pairs of partitions of $m$ with some properties, and the relation between them is that one has $n$ more parts than the other. But then the statement is not true:

- $a(4,1)=1$ because only $(\{3,1\}, \{4\})$ has both partitions with distinct parts such that the second contains more than the first.
- but $a(3,-1)>1$ because both $(\{3\}, \{3,0\})$ and $(\{3\}, \{2,1\})$ have the same properties.

That said, there is a lot of language here that I'm not used to.

- Does the word "representations" mean something special here?
- What word is "into" modifying?
- What is an "element" of a partition?

Probably this is really obvious, but right now I'm not seeing it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I read this as: count the number of pairs of partitions of $m$ each of which has distinct parts and where the number of elements in the first is $n$ more than the number in the second. But I haven't checked whether that satisfies the relation claimed.

Comment: @rogerl: I think this is the same version I was using: if I understand you correctly, the counterexample shows that the relation does not hold.

Comment: Actually, I still don't know what "number of elements" means. Particularly confusing because it also says "…two partitions into distinct parts…".

Comment: Is it possible that what he meant to say is that the number is the sum of all the numbers in both partitions? For example: a(4,1)=2 because 4 can be written as ({2,1},{1}) and ({3,1},{0}) and a(3,-1)=2 because 3 can be written as ({1},{2,0}) and ({2},{1,0}). If not, then I have no idea what could be the case here...

Comment: I read this as counting pairs of partitions ($\lambda$ is a partition into distinct parts of $k$, $\mu$ is a partition into distinct parts of $l$) such that $k+l=m$, $\lambda$ has $n$ more parts than $\mu$ with the complication of the $0$s.